# uploading files over current FTP content

Tags: ftp

a vital folder marked as System was deleted from ePublisher, the back end (administrator login) for a website, because of which a quick search feature cannot be performed. The developer of the website has compressed the website folder on his backup drive and sent it to me. He says I have to upload them over the current FTP content. What does that mean? What do I need to do exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unzip the file he sent you and upload it to the web server where the web site is hosted.

You'll need an FTP client (filezilla works for me) and the username/password to log on to the FTP server.

Once you're logged in paste the unzipped files you have received into the correct directory and you're done!